# Is "It would thus be" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Since my native language is *Dutch* it's not always evident to *"sense"* whether a given expression is grammatically sound or not.

A common expression in *Dutch* is: *"Het zou dus..."*. If one translates this (almost) literally, one obtains:

> **It would thus be** more efficient to work at night.

This sentence part however does not feel very "*English*". When [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20would%20thus%20be%22) the term, it gives a list of books, but since most of them are about meta-physics or by non-native English writers, it does not really resolve the problem...

Is the sentence-part correct? What are alternatives?

Comment: Can you provide more context, i.e., a full sentence?

Comment: @SEL: edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds fine! An alternative is to emphasize "thus" by placing it at the beginning. For example: "Thus, it would be more efficient to work at night."

Answer (score 5):

It appears that "*thus*" has been used in the sense of *"therefore".*

You can also consider:

- It would *therefore* be more efficient to work at night.

1 (used to introduce a logical conclusion) from that fact or reason or as a result

2 in the way indicated

Comment: +1 *Thus is fairly formal (often seen as pompous and even bordering on archaic), and found more in legal documents than in common parlance.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, "thus" is somewhat formal.

Colloquially we would use "so" and rephrase it:

**...so it would be more efficient to work at night.**